# Update a table with subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to update the STATUS column of the table

```
seq Req source  region count STATUS
1   1   C001    ABC     0     NULL
2   1   C001    DEF     0     NULL
3   1   C001    GHI     10    NULL
```

Based on the limit and comparison on the below table,

```
source  description symbol limit
----    ----------- ------ -----
c001    pass         >      10
c002    fail         =      0
```

I am using the query :

```
update table1 
   set a.STATUS = (select case b.symbol when '>' then case when a.c2 > b.limit then 'PASS' 
            else 'FAIL' end when '<' then case when a.c2 < b.limit 
            then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end when '=' then case when a.c2 = b.limit then 'PASS' 
            else 'FAIL' end end from table1 a join table2 b on a.source=b.source )
```

Please assist.

Comment: update table1  set a.STATUS =  
  (select case b.symbol
      when '>' then
        case when  a.c2 > b.limit then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end
      when '<' then
        case when  a.c2  < b.limit then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end
      when '=' then
        case when  a.c2  = b.limit then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end
    end 
  from table1 a 
  join table2 b on a.source=b.source

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
update table1  a
   set STATUS = (select (case when b.symbol = '>' and a.c2 > b.limit or
                                   b.symbol = '<' and a.c2 < b.limit or
                                   b.symbol = '=' and a.c2 = b.limit 
                              then 'PASS' else 'FAIL'
                         end)
                 from table2 b 
                 where a.source = b.source
                );
```

Comment: how do we update the rows that only have the max(req_id) on the table1 ?

Comment: @Chand . . . That seems like a different question.  New questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Comment: sorry about that. let me post a new question now